# The order of field in basic page

Tags: 7, entities

I added a field image to my basic page and I set it to be displayed first. The problem is that the image still display after the field body.

How can I change the order in which those fields are shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure -> Content Types -> Your Type -> Manage display-> Change the position of image field with plus icon -> Save

Comment: this is exactly what i have done before but it dosen't work !!!

Comment: Sorry, i updated the answer :)

Comment: thanks @xurshid29 it works now i thought it was 'manage fields' :)